# How to limit the width of window entries on the Wibar?

Tags: awesome-wm

Right now if I open only a window, it fills all of the **wibar** completely. Until I open another window, now each takes half of the space.

Is there a way to set a *static width* that a single window can take on the **wibar**?

This is an example:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DhnDT.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is several ways to do this. I will list some of them and the pros/cons

By default, the `awful.widget.tasklist` widget uses `wibox.layout.flex.horizontal`, which distribute the width. You want to replace it by `wibox.layout.fixed.horizontal`, which defaults to the widget preferred size. You also want to add a `forced_width` if you want the width to always be the same.

[image]

```lua
    -- Create a tasklist widget
    s.mytasklist = awful.widget.tasklist {
        screen  = s,
        filter  = awful.widget.tasklist.filter.currenttags,
        layout  = wibox.layout.fixed.horizontal(),
        widget_template = {
            {
                {
                    {
                        {
                            widget = awful.widget.clienticon,
                        },
                        margins = 2,
                        widget  = wibox.container.margin,
                    },
                    {
                        id     = "text_role",
                        widget = wibox.widget.textbox,
                    },
                    layout = wibox.layout.fixed.horizontal,
                },
                left  = 10,
                right = 10,
                widget = wibox.container.margin
            },
            forced_width = 100,
            id     = "background_role",
            widget = wibox.container.background,
        },
        buttons = tasklist_buttons
    }
```

But you might also want to wrap this in a [wibox.container.constraint](https://awesomewm.org/apidoc/widget_containers/wibox.container.constraint.html) container. This gives you the ability to set a minimum/maximum size rather than hardcode the value.

Comment: Thank you! What would you suggest to do if I set a fixed width, but the tasklist is full? The new entries disappear in this case.. Is there a way to limit the width capacity of the wibar?

Comment: You can limit the number using a filter. Or you can use `wibox.container.constraint` to get finer grained control over the time. You could also use a grid if you fear you will run out of space.

Comment: Thank you, it looks like you already put this in your original answer. What I meant is that I can't figure out how to use `wibox.container.constraint` in code. `widget = wibox.container.constraint(wibox.container.background, 'max', 50,100),` is this correct?

Comment: It can work that way, but it's better to wrap the whole widget template into another dept lever of `{}`, then use the constrains container properties rather than pass everything in the constructor.

Comment: `wibox.container.constraint` behaviour is unstable. When the bar is full the tasks get randomly resized. What would be very nice is to have exactly the same code above, but switch to `wibox.layout.flex.horizontal` when the bar is full. Would this be possible? (Thank you for all of your help).